# Limiting SSH to machine on local network

Tags: ssh, raspberry-pi

Hi– I've never needed to set up SSH before, so I'm new to this. I have a Raspberry Pi managing my smart-devices, that I would like to be able to SSH into. However **only** from another machine on the local network.

I want to use keys instead of passwords, but I am not sure how to get started. I have been told that `ufw` is one way, and that I will need to set up my `sshd`; but that is about all I know.

Is there any thing else that I need to do?

Comment: You seem to know what places to look for, what do you expect from us? Write a complete tutorial for you? Why not search the site for related questions first? http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/

Comment: What is the specific problem you're having? Configuring ufw? Installing sshd? Creating keys?

Comment: @Panki, there's no need to use a URL to describe your opinion. Vote your conscience and use the comment to describe what you think needs to be improved. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Force key based authentication

- set `PasswordAuthentication no` in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`

## Block from other networks

```
ufw allow proto tcp from 192.168.1.0/24 to any port 22 comment "ssh"
ufw enable
```

I only tested syntax on first line. You will also have to change the IP-network-address. My example is for `192.168.1.x`.

Answer (score 0):

1. On the smart devices (ssh server side), you need sshd. Find out how to enable it for each device.
2. Using password ssh access, use the client tools (below) to set up key access.
3. Then disable password access as shown in the answer by ctrl-alt-delor above.

Here are the tools for the client (sshd not needed on client) you need to learn about:
ssh-keygen, and ssh-add or ssh-id-copy